# MAAS/Autopilot install enable console

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

In Autopilot install of Openstack I see that I don't have console enabled. Googled it and only found below as a solution. Thing is I don't have nova-cloud-controller installed at all using autopilot.

```
juju deploy nova-cloud-controller
juju set nova-cloud-controller "console-access-protocol=novnc"
```

If I try adding it juju complains with cannot run instances:

```
cannot run instances: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 409 CONFLICT (No available node matches constraints)
```

Any ideas?